# With structure - using multiple select queries without repeating the "with"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to use a with structure with multiple sql select queries. Ex:

```
;with temptable as ( ... )
select id from temptable
select name from temptable
```

However after the first select query is done, `SQL Server 2008` doesnt allow me to do it and it pushes me to write the same with structure again above the second query. Ex:

```
;with temptable as ( ... )
select id from temptable
;with temptable as ( ... )
select name from temptable
```

I tried using comma after the first select query but didnt work. How can I use multiple select queries under one with structure in `SQL Server 2008`.

Comment: `SELECT .... INTO #temptable FROM ...` and then `select id from #temptable;
select name from #temptable;` Does it help in your case?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want to do with it? What kind of data  are you going to query and what are the desired results?

Comment: Why would you not want a single query `SELECT id, name FROM temptable`?  Why would you want to risk getting the names in a different order from the ids?

Comment: @lad2025 thanks this is the idea I was looking for. Write it as answer then I will mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) works only for one statement.

> Specifies a temporary named result set, known as a common table
>   expression (CTE). This is derived from a simple query and defined
>   within the execution scope of a **single** SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement.

```
select id from temptable;
select name from temptable;
```

are two statements, so you cannot use it in second query.

The alternative is to use temp table:

```
SELECT .... INTO #temptable FROM ...; -- your query from CTE
SELECT id   FROM #temptable; 
SELECT name FROM #temptable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CTE only exists for the "duration of the query" you can't use the same CTE in two different SELECT statements as each is a separate query.
you need to store the result set of CTE into temp table to and fire multiple select statements on temp table.

;with temptable as ( ... )
select id 
into #tempResultSet
from temptable

select name from tempResultSet
```